# Loading different version assemblies, what dependency assemblies will be loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I am writing an app that will use different versions of assemblies and call their methods. Question is, what dependency assemblies will they use.

For example :

- `AbcV1.dll` has dependency assembly `General.dll`, both files located
  in `\App\V1`
- `AbcV2.dll` has dependency assembly `General.dll`, both
  files located in `\App\V2`

Application also has dependency assembly `General.dll`, located with executable.

Lets assume `General.dll` is also not same in all folders, its changed too.

Now, when application will load `AbcV1.dll` and `AbcV2.dll` by reflection. Will they use their own `General.dll` or they will use Application's `General.dll` ?